# how to rank row for same repeating value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given this data how can give rank for each repeating data. 1 to 5 i want to rank as 1 and next 1 to 5 i want to rank as 2

Data

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Expecting output

Data | Column

```
1     1
2     1
3     1 
4     1  
5     1
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     2
```

I was trying to implement using row number but Below is the exact requirement that i have to implement :

```
Refcol value column

    1  refers to time
    2  refers to name
    3  refers to location
    4  refers to Available (1 or 0 or null)


ID | Refcol | Metric 
1     1       02/02/2022
1     2       Adam
1     3       Japan
1     4       1 
1     1       03/02/2022
1     2       Smith 
1     3       England 
1     4       0
```

Now i want to transform above data as shown below

**Expected Ouput**

```
ID | time        |  name | location | Available
1    02/02/2022     Adam    Japan      1
1    03/02/2022     Smith   England    0
```

Comment: Data in a relational table is unordered, how you happen to show it on screen is irrelevant.

Comment: For the updated issue with more sample data, you need some way of grouping the first 4 rows from the source data, then the next 4 rows. You need some sort of "set identifier". As is, there's no way to distinguish that "Smith" belongs to the second set of data with date of 3/2/2022. Smith could just as easily belong to the first set with date of 2/2/2022.

Comment: in ref column first 1 to 4 contains first employee and next 1 to 4 next employee, metric col contains employee info how can i transform this data into rows

Comment: i am not grouping by date i am grouping by refcol and want to transfrom into rows

Comment: @shubhamsingh I understand exactly what you're trying to do. And I'm trying to explain that your data structure doesn't guarantee any solution will work consistently. I've updated my answer with a new fiddle showing one way to work with your data as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you can do with the limited sample data is to create a row number for each time a number appears. Then order by the row number and then the number. If this doesn't work, then show us more real data.

When using ROW_NUMBER, there's no guarantee that the first 1 through 5 group will be ordered correctly. You have to have some other identifier to guarantee the ordering (i.e. time stamp, set number, parent group, etc.).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c2959e/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (
  num int not null
  );
  
INSERT INTO Numbers
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH prelim AS (
  SELECT n.num
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY n.num ORDER BY n.num ASC) as row_num
  FROM Numbers as n
)
SELECT
  p.num
  , p.row_num
FROM prelim as p
ORDER BY p.row_num, p.num
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c2959e/2/0)**:

```
| num | row_num |
|-----|---------|
|   1 |       1 |
|   2 |       1 |
|   3 |       1 |
|   4 |       1 |
|   5 |       1 |
|   1 |       2 |
|   2 |       2 |
|   3 |       2 |
|   4 |       2 |
|   5 |       2 |
```

UPDATE: If you are dead-set on not changing the data structure, then the best you can do is loop through the data and assigning a unique SetID number to each group of 4 rows. There is no guarantee that this will work when you have more than 4 rows in the table since you have no column to guarantee a consistent sort order.

```
CREATE TABLE attributes (
  ID int not null
  , RefCol int not null
  , Metric nvarchar(50) not null
  , SetID int null
);

INSERT INTO attributes (ID, RefCol, Metric) 
VALUES 
  (1,1,'02/02/2022')
  ,(1,2,'Adam')
  ,(1,3,'Japan')
  ,(1,4,'1')
  ,(1,1,'03/02/2022')
  ,(1,2,'Smith')
  ,(1,3,'England')
  ,(1,4,'0')
;

DECLARE @setID int = 0;

WHILE (EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM attributes WHERE SetID is NULL))
BEGIN
  UPDATE TOP (4) attributes
  SET SetID = @setID
  FROM attributes
  WHERE SetID IS NULL
  ;

  SET @setID = @setID + 1;
END

SELECT * FROM attributes;

SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.SetID
  , a.ID
  , aTime.Metric as [time]
  , aName.Metric as [name]
  , aLoc.Metric as [location]
  , aAvail.Metric as [Available]
FROM attributes as a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN attributes as aTime
    ON aTime.SetID = a.SetID
    AND aTime.RefCol = 1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN attributes as aName
    ON aName.SetID = a.SetID
    AND aName.RefCol = 2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN attributes as aLoc
    ON aLoc.SetID = a.SetID
    AND aLoc.RefCol = 3
  LEFT OUTER JOIN attributes as aAvail
    ON aAvail.SetID = a.SetID
    AND aAvail.RefCol = 4
;
```

| ID | RefCol | Metric | SetID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 02/02/2022 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | Adam | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | Japan | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 03/02/2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | Smith | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | England | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | 1 |

| SetID | ID | time | name | location | Available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 02/02/2022 | Adam | Japan | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 03/02/2022 | Smith | England | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kP85YAQ7)

Comment: Hi Tim , I have updated the exact requirement that could please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off asking the question you actually have.

The result you want can be achieved from the data you gave, but it's going to be non-deterministic.

```
DECLARE @ints TABLE (INT INT)
INSERT INTO @ints (INT) VALUES
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5),
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
```

```
SELECT INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INT ORDER BY INT) AS rn
  FROM @ints
 ORDER BY rn, INT
```

```
INT rn
------
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   2
```